# Align QLabel with custom QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qlabel

I'm new to Qt programming and I want to align a QLabel with a custom QGraphicsItem i created. Here's inside my custom item constructor:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setText("Some Text");
pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

the last line seems to have no effect whether its AlignLeft, Center, or Right. 
myItem is a custom rectangle, and I'd like the label to be centered inside the rectangle, as it is the first word of label is being centered at the rectangle instead of the center of the label.

Please help

Comment: why you need `QLabel` inside of `QGraphicsProxyWidget`? It is pointless since there are `QGraphicsItems` which can cover `QLabel` functionality. `QGraphicsProxyWidget` should be used if you wish to use some complex widget without porting it to `QGraphicsView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a widget through a proxy, the proxy is the child of the initial item so its position will be relative to it and by default the position is `(0, 0)`, so you see that although you set an alignment does not change, what you must do to place it in the center through `setPos()`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

    QGraphicsRectItem *item = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    item->setRect(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200));
    item->setBrush(Qt::red);
    scene->addItem(item);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(item);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    label->setText("Some Text");
    pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
    pMyProxy->setPos(item->boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
    w.setScene(scene);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

---

Assuming `this` is the item, you should do the following:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget *pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setText("Some Text");
pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
pMyProxy->setPos(boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
```

---

If you want to access the widget regarding the item you must follow the children tree:

```
QGraphiscScene
└── QGraphiscItem
    └── (children)
        QGraphicsProxyWidget
        └── (widget)
            QLabel
```

Example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

    QGraphicsRectItem *item = new QGraphicsRectItem;
    item->setRect(QRect(0, 0, 200, 200));
    item->setBrush(Qt::red);
    scene->addItem(item);
    item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *pMyProxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(item);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();
    label->setText("Some Text");
    pMyProxy->setWidget(label);
    pMyProxy->setPos(item->boundingRect().center()-label->rect().center());
    w.setScene(scene);
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
        if(!scene->selectedItems().isEmpty()){
            auto *item = scene->selectedItems().first();
            if(!item->childItems().isEmpty()){
                auto proxy = static_cast<QGraphicsProxyWidget *>(item->childItems().first());
                if(proxy){
                    auto label = qobject_cast<QLabel *>(proxy->widget());
                    if(label){
                        label->setText(QString("x: %1, y: %2").arg(item->pos().x()).arg(item->pos().y()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start(100);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Now I'm trying to create an action to change my items label. So I created a slot in my mainwindow to handle it, I was retrieving my item infos using **scene->selectedItems().first();**. But it returns me a QGraphicsItem, how can I access the QLabel object since I'm using a proxy?

Comment: @MatheusIanzer I have given an example of how to access the QLabel, later when I have time I will publish a better solution.